# Why matplotlib rotates my original image?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, image-rotation

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KHtMRFBijOn4e2rWoVo3gfP3j3RY4cpo/view?usp=sharing) image (note: it is fake publicly available image)

I did:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = Image.open("yolov5_dataset/images/test/photo_alb_id.json_98.jpg")
plt.imshow(image)
```

and it shows:

[image]

why it rotates the original image? Other images are displayed correctly.

Comment: Like for the other images, I would expect an image's pixels to be stored starting (0,0) at the top left, incrementing left to right and then top to bottom, ending (2300,4000) at the bottom right. But for this image, it's starting at the top *right*, incrementing top to bottom then right to left, ending at the bottom left.

Comment: It is not matplotlib, but `Image.open(...)` that doesn't seem to take into account the rotation. Which library are you using? Did you try matplotlib (`plt.imread()`)? Does it also happen with all other jpeg images, or only this one? Maybe you could load and save the photo again in the correct orientation using an external program (gimp, irfanview, ...)?

Comment: @BatWannaBe How do I know which method was used for which image? The consequences of this rotation is that I have bounding box coordinates of the id-card and it messes up when the image is rotated.

Comment: @JohanC I'm using `matplotlib` and `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` .No, haven't tried `plt.imread`.

Comment: @JohanC Oh! I see.. I'm using `from PIL import Image`

Comment: I think is jupyter which rotate the image to save space. Try to run your code in the terminal

Comment: You folks are inventing wild technical explanations for what is a very simple issue.  The phone that took this picture is in portrait (wide) format, as virtually all cameras are..  What you're seeing there IS the actual image that the camera took.  The PHONE knows which direction is up and down because of its gravity sensors.  It embeds the actual orientation in the JPEG metadata.  Some applications use that metadata to do a rotation after opening the image, but not all.  If you want this fixed, go rotate it in an image manipulation app.

Comment: Can you upload the image in the question ? I am unable to download the pic.